# Magento DB query to large for mySQL

Tags: mysql, database, magento, categories

Magento DB query to large works the first time then crashes.

I have about 6000 products and I need to put my category's into alphabetical order. The first time I make a move it takes about 45 min and works. Then any after that fail. mySQL is still up and going on other sites. but if I restart mySQL then it will not start back up. I have to safe reboot twice.... wait a bit then it seems to reset and will work. how do i let it run a larger query or is there another way to move/organize the categories?

If any one can help I would appreciate it so much.

Thanks

P.s. any more info needed please ask.

Notification Type:  failed 
Notification:   mysql failed @ Mon Jul 1 13:27:34 2013. A restart was attempted automagically. 
Service Check Method:    [check command] 
Number of Restart Attempts: 1 
Service Check Raw Output:
mysql is not running 
Restart Message:
Stuck on restart of mysql at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/TailWatch/ChkServd.pm line 1013. 
Startup Log:
Starting MySQL.... SUCCESS! 
Memory Information: 
Used: 348MB 
Available: 3099MB 
Installed: 3447MB 
Load Information:   18.49 12.34 6.95 
Uptime: 199 days, 16 hours, 39 seconds 
IOStat Information: 
avg-cpu: %user %nice %system %iowait %steal %idle 
0.44 0.23 0.31 0.84 0.00 98.18 
Device: tps Blk_read/s Blk_wrtn/s Blk_read Blk_wrtn 
vda 30.25 103.89 151.29 1792508458 2610237768 
vda1 30.25 103.89 151.29 1792508098 2610237768 
vdb 0.01 0.19 0.25 3278144 4279560

Comment: I've heard this complaint before. I believe the problem lies in the indexer processes Magento triggers after moving a category. Have you tried to set the indexers to manual update temporarily? Due to renaming a category a lot of product URL's etc need to be rewritten by the indexer.

Comment: Tim, setting the indexers to manual did the trick. For a bit i was thinking i would have to do this through the shell but they are in the admin on the index page. select the index and change to manual. easy easy and hours of waiting now gone. Thanks so much

Comment: Good to hear. It's best to set them back to automatic when you are done adjusted the category sequence. Please mark your question as answered, so the rest of the community knowns this thread is answered/finished.